# Truffle migrate code with library, interface and contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-20

Suppose that I have a token contract as follow. How can i write the new `migration.js` file in truffle to deploy the contract?

TestCoin.sol

```
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract ERC20 is IERC20 {

}

contract TestCoin is ERC20 {

}
```

1_initial_migration.js

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

I am thinking of something like this but not sure if it is correct

```
var SafeMath = artifacts.require("./SafeMath.sol");
var TestCoin = artifacts.require("./TestCoin.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SafeMath);
  deployer.link(SafeMath, TestCoin);
  deployer.deploy(TestCoin);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, There are two types of libraries:

1. All with internal method

   - These type of libraries are not deployed  explicitly they are included in contract itself. ie. SafeMath from openzeppelin.
   - Internal libraries don't need to be linked with main contract.
   - They are included in contract's bytecode itself.
   - Consider following library:

   ```js
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    // library for uint array 
    library UintArrayLib {
        using UintArrayLib for uints;

        struct uints {
            uint[] array;
        }

        function add(uints storage self, uint _uint)
            internal
        {
            if(! exists(self, _uint)){
                self.array.push(_uint);
            }
        }

        function remove(
            uints storage self,
            uint _uint
        ) internal {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < self.array.length; i++) {
                if (
                    self.array[i] == _uint 
                ) {
                    delete self.array[i];
                }
            }
        }


        function exists(
            uints storage self,
            uint _uint
        ) internal view returns (bool) {
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < self.array.length; i++) {
                if (
                    self.array[i] == _uint 
                ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    contract BuyList is Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
        using UintArrayLib for UintArrayLib.uints;
        // Rest of the code goes here
    }
   ```

   - For deploying BuyList contract, You'll write following migration:

   ```js
   var BuyList = artifacts.require("BuyList");

   module.exports = function(deployer) {
       deployer.deploy(BuyList);
   };
   ```
2. At least one public method

   - These contract's public method are not included contract directly and the whole library is deployed explicitly as new address.
   - These libraries needs to be linked to the main contract.
   - These libraries are not included in contract's bytecode and mostly used when the contract reaches the max bytecode size limit.
   - consider the following library example.

   ```
   pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
   // library for uint array 
   library UintArrayLib {
       using UintArrayLib for uints;

       struct uints {
           uint[] array;
       }

       function add(uints storage self, uint _uint)
           public
       {
           if(! exists(self, _uint)){
               self.array.push(_uint);
           }
       }

       function remove(
           uints storage self,
           uint _uint
       ) public {
       for (uint256 i = 0; i < self.array.length; i++) {
               if (
                   self.array[i] == _uint 
               ) {
                   delete self.array[i];
               }
           }
       }


       function exists(
           uints storage self,
           uint _uint
       ) internal view returns (bool) {
           for (uint256 i = 0; i < self.array.length; i++) {
               if (
                   self.array[i] == _uint 
               ) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
   }

   contract BuyList is Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
       using UintArrayLib for UintArrayLib.uints;
       // Rest of the code goes here
   }
   ```

   - For deploying BuyList contract, You'll write following migration:

   ```js
   var UintArrayLib = artifacts.require("UintArrayLib");
   var BuyList = artifacts.require("BuyList");

   module.exports = function(deployer) {
       deployer.deploy(UintArrayLib); // Explicity deployment of lib
       deployer.link(UintArrayLib, BuyList); // Linking the lib
       deployer.deploy(BuyList); // Deploying main contract
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, but you need linkind for truffle when you explicitly use imported libraries, meanwhile you can use:

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TestCoin is ERC20 {
}
```

Deployment script:

```
var TestCoin = artifacts.require("./TestCoin.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(TestCoin);
};
```

Comment: What do you mean? You mention need linking for truffle when explicitly use imported libraries but in the deployment script example u show did not use link to library

Comment: 1. Truffle will not ask to link external library. 2. If you use migration for testing purposes you don't need to link `SafeMath` with `TestCoin`, because you don't use `SafeMath` in constructor

Comment: I omit the using SafeMath in the code for sample code. .. in the actual code there is using safemath. so do i need to link SafeMath?

Comment: and what does it mean by truffle will not ask to link external library

Comment: external library is library from `npm` package (`openzeppelin-solidity`), when you use the library you don't need to link.